# Asp.Net MVC Sorting attribute for model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, attributes

I am wondering if we have any attribute like [orderby] for model? 
Do we have any custom attribute or plugin which sorts my model values?

```
[orderby]
public string Names { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing as `[OrderBy]` attribute. And it does not make sense to apply attribute like this. Collections are sortable, not properties in the object. You'll have to do your sorting in the controller or methods that provide collections to controller.